# SQL use column from subselect in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, subquery

I have a query that looks something like that:

```
SELECT a, b, c,
    (SELECT d from B limit 0,1) as d
FROM A
WHERE d >= 10
```

I get the result that I want when I run the query without the `where`clause but when I add the `where` clause the query fails.

Does anyone have a suggestion how to solve that?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can't use a column alias in `WHERE` clause.

So you either wrap your query in an outer select and apply your condition there

```
SELECT * 
  FROM
(
  SELECT a, b, c,
    (SELECT d FROM B LIMIT 0,1) d
  FROM A
) q
 WHERE d >= 10
```

or you can introduce that condition in `HAVING` clause instead

```
SELECT a, b, c,
    (SELECT d FROM B LIMIT 0,1) d
  FROM A
HAVING d >= 10
```

Yet another approach is to use `CROSS JOIN` and apply your condition in `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT a, b, c, d
  FROM A CROSS JOIN 
(
  SELECT d FROM B LIMIT 0,1
) q
 WHERE d >= 10
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c2d4/9)** demo for all above mentioned queries.

Comment: very helpful, +1 for mentioning the very ufseful SqlFiddle:)

Comment: Good that you mentioned HAVING, as it's been always thought to be useful only with GROUP BY.

Comment: What are the impacts on performance when using query wrapping vs. the having clause vs. cross join?

Answer (score 0):

Is this  what you want?

```
SELECT a, b, c,
    B.d
FROM A, (SELECT d from B limit 0,1) B
WHERE B.d >= 10
```

Comment: Nope, because if for example d is not >= 10 this column would simply be empty but I want if the where clause doesn't match that the entire row will not be displayed

Comment: @Chris is there any realtion between TableA and TalbeB ?

Comment: Sorry, I have not environment to test. I changed the sql. How about this time?