# Writing subqueries in SQL

Tags: postgresql, subquery

I'm learning PostgreSQL and I have a database log that has these columns: path text, ip inet, method text, status text, time timestamptz, id int

Using this database my goal is to find any days that have a error percent (status != '200 OK' / status) of over 2.5 percent. I have the query, seen below, that gets to the error percent as a decimal but I can't figure out how to multiply them by 10 to make them a 'percent' nor how to check if they are over 2.5.

I have tried both HAVING and WHERE in multiple spots but I either get a Programming error at group by or a syntax error wherever I enter the HAVING or WHERE. What's the correct way to change it to a percent and check if its over 2.5? Thanks in advance

Mock data:

```
CREATE TABLE log (
    path text,
    ip inet,
    method text,
    status text,
    "time" timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now(),
    id integer NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO log VALUES ('/article/bears-love-berries', '198.51.100.76' , 'GET', '200 OK', '2016-07-1 12:54:22+00', 3355597);
INSERT INTO log VALUES ('/article/candidate-is-jerk', '198.51.100.76' , 'GET', '200 OK', '2016-07-1 19:54:22+00', 3355598);
INSERT INTO log VALUES ('/article/bears-love-berries', '198.51.100.76' , 'GET', '404 NOT FOUND', '2016-07-1 22:54:22+00', 3355599);
INSERT INTO log VALUES ('/article/goats-eat-googles', '203.0.113.42' , 'GET', '200 OK', '2016-07-11 12:54:22+00', 3355600);
INSERT INTO log VALUES ('/article/candidate-is-jerk', '203.0.113.42' , 'GET', '200 OK', '2016-07-11 17:54:22+00', 3355601);
INSERT INTO log VALUES ('/article/bears-love-berries', '203.0.113.42' , 'GET', '200 OK', '2016-07-11 19:54:22+00', 3355602);
INSERT INTO log VALUES ('/article/goats-eat-googles', '203.0.113.42' , 'GET', '404 NOT FOUND', '2016-07-15 13:54:22+00', 3355603);
INSERT INTO log VALUES ('/article/bears-love-berries', '198.51.100.34' , 'GET', '200 OK', '2016-07-15 20:54:22+00', 3355604);
INSERT INTO log VALUES ('/article/candidate-is-jerk', '198.51.100.34' , 'GET', '200 OK', '2016-07-15 23:54:22+00', 3355605);
INSERT INTO log VALUES ('/article/candidate-is-jerk', '203.0.113.12' , 'GET', '200 OK', '2016-07-21 19:54:22+00', 3355606);
INSERT INTO log VALUES ('/article/bears-love-berries', '203.0.113.12' , 'GET', '200 OK', '2016-07-21 12:54:22+00', 3355607);
INSERT INTO log VALUES ('/article/goats-eat-googles', '198.51.100.76' , 'GET', '200 OK', '2016-07-21 01:54:22+00', 3355608);
INSERT INTO log VALUES ('/article/goats-eat-googles', '198.51.100.76' , 'GET', '404 NOT FOUND', '2016-07-29 07:54:22+00', 3355609);
INSERT INTO log VALUES ('/article/candidate-is-jerk', '198.51.100.76' , 'GET', '404 NOT FOUND', '2016-07-29 20:54:22+00', 3355610);
INSERT INTO log VALUES ('/article/goats-eat-googles', '198.51.100.34' , 'GET', '200 OK', '2016-07-29 19:54:22+00', 3355611);
```

Query:

```
SELECT DATE(time) AS day,
(
  (SELECT CAST(COUNT(status) AS FLOAT)
  FROM log WHERE status != '200 OK') /
  (SELECT CAST(COUNT(status) AS FLOAT))
) AS views
FROM log GROUP BY day
ORDER BY views
```

Comment: Decompose the problem into smaller problems.  What is a percent?  It's a ratio of two numbers.  What are the two numbers?  You need a count status = 200 and a count of status != 200.  I think if you can count the errors per day, you'll find the rest to be easy.

Comment: @Brandon I can find the count of the status != 200 and the count of the overall requests each day. The question is how do I test if the ratio of the two is greater than 2.5 percent, to put a WHERE or HAVING on the outer SELECT it has a syntax error or a column views not found error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After sharing a test case in sqlfiddle, we could get down to a running code that would do it.

The fiddle is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b3ed9/39

Instead of multiplicating the result by 100 you can just check against the already-multiplied 0.025, no? I mean, if you have values between 0-1, the equivalent to 2.5% would be just 0.025.

Thus that command should do:

```
select views.day, views.cnt from
 (select datelog.day,
  (
   cast(count(case when datelog.status != '200 OK' then 1 else null end) as float)
   /
   cast(count(*) as float)
  ) as cnt
  from (select DATE(time) as day, status from log) as datelog
  group by datelog.day
 ) as views
 where views.cnt > 0.025
```

The last revision was deeply founded in the reply here: [SQL use column from subselect in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18029786/sql-use-column-from-subselect-in-where-clause)

Comment: I tried both this and HAVING but I get ProgrammingError: Column 'views' does not exist? Also the reason I'm trying to get it to be 2.5 and not 0.025 is I need to present it to python to display it without having to update ie times by 100 in python.

Comment: And when I do HAVING instead of where I get a syntax error on GROUP BY not the column error

Comment: Don't you think you missed a parens on your two subselect? I mean, I read <outer_select> <select_a> / (<select_b>) AS views -- so instead <outer_select> (<select_a> / <select_b>) AS views shouldn't do it?

Comment: Woops I accidently mistyped the post, but no it is still giving a views does not exist error

Comment: You are also missing 'FROM log' on your second sub-query. :)

Comment: Yes I was missing that, thank you, but the same error is still persisting, any idea why?

Comment: alright, the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18029786/sql-use-column-from-subselect-in-where-clause

I will edit my answer from that one, hope you'll understand what's the point. Basically wrap your whole query as if it were a table. Then the where goes into action.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145161/discussion-between-will-scott-and-avenger).