# Check existence of a result from sub query in SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do I get not-null results from a sub query in SELECT statement?

```
SELECT a, b, c,
       (SELECT d 
        FROM table2
        WHERE ...) as d
FROM table 1
WHERE ...
```

I want to get results only when all values (a, b, c , d) not Null.
It won't be kind of weird/non-efficient to use the same sub-query in main WHERE clause as well but with EXISTS?

Comment: Easiest way is to put all that in another query: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT a, b, c, (SELECT d ...) FROM ...) AS x WHERE x IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Can you be more specific? Please provide some example of what you need to do..

Comment: What's your expected result because `d` column from table2.

Comment: JOIN the sub-query instead!

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Can you show some data an the expected result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL use column from subselect in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18029786/sql-use-column-from-subselect-in-where-clause)

Comment: @eurotrash I like your solution - it works and elegant. Unfortunately, I can't mark it as an answer

Comment: @Agenobarb No problem, I'll put it as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to put your original query in a subquery, then you can check whether the whole row that the subquery returns is NULL:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT a, b, c,
           (SELECT d 
            FROM table2
            WHERE ...)
    FROM table 1
    WHERE ...
) AS sub
WHERE sub IS NOT NULL
```

`sub` being the row of `(a,b,c,d)` returned by the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
 t1.a,
 t1.b,
 t1.c, 
 t2.d
FROM table1 t1
left join table2 as t2 on t2.ID = t1.ID
WHERE t1.a is not null and t1.b is not null and t1.c is not null and t2.d is not null
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery:

```
select a, b, c, d
from (SELECT a, b, c,
             (SELECT d 
              FROM table2
              WHERE ...) as d
      FROM table 1
      WHERE ... and
            a is not null and b is not null and c is not null
     ) x
where d is not null;
```

In all likelihood, though, you can use `JOIN`:

```
SELECT a, b, c, x.d 
FROM table 1 JOIN
      (SELECT d 
        FROM table2
        WHERE ...
     ) x
WHERE ... and
      a is not null and b is not null and c is not null and d is not null;
```